# Visual DataFlex Reg Exp

Tags: regex, dataflex

I'm trying to implement into my simple app a very basic regular expression..
Can someone provide me an example ?

I use to develop in obj-c, php and javascript so usually exp are similar to

myExp = /pattern/

How to do this in DataFlex ?

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use the package available in the Data Access forums or simply use the VB DLL that other developers use (also discussed in the attached thread):

[Text compare function - generalTextCompare.txt](http://support.dataaccess.com/Forums/showthread.php?1064-Text-compare-function-generalTextCompare.txt-%280-1%29&p=192911&highlight=regular%20expressions#post192911)